# Duplicate tags [lexical-scope] and [lexical-scoping]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[lexical-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-scope) and [lexical-scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-scoping) are about the same thing. Funnily enough, the description of [lexical-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-scope) starts with »Lexical scoping«, and the description of [lexical-scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-scoping) starts with »Lexical scope«.